# php array manipulation help

Tags: php

I have an array with words below as an example.

```
$words = array('hello','world','wad','up','yo','etc');
```

what  i want is next array with following by manipulating above

```
$phrase2 = array('hello world', 'world wad', 'wad up', 'up  yo', 'yo etc');
$phrase3 = array('hello world wad', 'world wad up', 'wad up yo', 'up  yo etc');
$phrase4 = array('hello world wad up', 'world wad up yo', 'wad up yo etc');
$phrase5 = array('hello world wad up yo', 'world wad up yo etc');
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: ohh now i understand. I would take care of it now. not fixed can be more or less from time to time. I am developing a site where i need to use this knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice array and then implode the results:

```
$words = array('hello','world','wad','up','yo','etc');
$phrase2 = array();
$phrase3 = array();
$phrase4 = array();
$lim = sizeof($words);
for($i=0;$i<$lim;$i++)
{
    if($i < $lim - 1)
        $phrase2[] = implode(" ",array_slice($words,$i,2)); 
    if($i < $lim - 2)
        $phrase3[] = implode(" ",array_slice($words,$i,3)); 
    if($i < $lim - 3)
        $phrase4[] = implode(" ",array_slice($words,$i,4)); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. It may not be optimised but still it answers the OP

Answer (score 3):

Instead of $phrase2, $phrase3, ... my code uses $phrase[2], $phrase[3], ...

But if you want to use $phrase2, $phrase3, $phrase4, then just add the following code to the end of mine:

```
$phrase2 = $phrase[2];
$phrase3 = $phrase[3];
$phrase4 = $phrase[4];
$phrase5 = $phrase[5];
```

Here my code, **just try it!**:

```
<?php
$words = array('hello','world','wad','up','yo','etc');
$phrase = array();
for($i=2; $i<=count($words); $i++)
{
    foreach($words as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key <= count($words)-$i)
        {
            $phrase_value[] = $value;

            for($j=1; $j<$i; $j++)
            {
                $phrase_value[] = $words[$key+$j];
            }

            $phrase[$i][] = implode(' ', $phrase_value);
            unset($phrase_value);
        }
    }
}
// this deletes the last array in phrase
array_pop($phrase);
?>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world
            [1] => world wad
            [2] => wad up
            [3] => up yo
            [4] => yo etc
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world wad
            [1] => world wad up
            [2] => wad up yo
            [3] => up yo etc
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world wad up
            [1] => world wad up yo
            [2] => wad up yo etc
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world wad up yo
            [1] => world wad up yo etc
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world wad up yo etc
        )

)
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/j6aUo2tm it works but 2 things : the OP wanted 4 `arrays` and not 1 with 4 arrays inside + there's 1 more array in your code than asked. ;)

Comment: $phrase2 = $phrase[2]; $phrase3 = $phrase[3], $phrase4 = $phrase[4]; and so on ;) Wheres the problem?

Comment: That's not what's asked. If that's what I supposed, it's homework. Considering this, you can't change facts that what's asked are 4 single arrays and not 1 big one ;) Plus, you got `$phrase6` which isn't asked (and easily done with a small change in your code)

Comment: @ahmet2106 : Don't take it personally, right. I agree with you, it's easier to handle your way if you don't know how many iterator he wants (really, see my codepad in the first comment, you just need a `foreach` to show every arrays then). Still, you need to modify your code to have one less array in the big one as asked ;)

Comment: You could make a modification to do something like this to put it into $phrase2, $phrase3, etc. `$$var = "phrase$i"` and `array_push($$var, implode(' ', $phrase_value);` - This will also require an initialize phase so that `$$var` is an array()

Comment: @Shikiryu now added array_pop(); to delete '6' (the last of $phrase)

Comment: @Josh : Well, some people here doesn't like variable variables. Anyway, it can be a solution here since we don't know the OP's conditions

Comment: Hello could you guys suggest what should i do if this is to be run on array of more than 500 words?

Comment: @askkirati this code will run with any array, doenst matter how long your array is ;-) but dont use $phrase1, $phrase2 and so on. Its easier with an array as result..

Comment: @askkirati : Just consider `$words = array('hello','world','wad','up','yo','etc');` as your 500 words array.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this for my programming exercise.

```
<?php

$src1 = "hello world wad up yo etc";
$words = explode(" ",$src1);
$length = count($words);
print_r($words);

$phrases = array();

foreach( range(2,5) as $span ){
    $shifter = create_function("\$n","{ global \$words; return join(\" \", array_slice(\$words,\$n,$span) ); }");
    $sp = array_map( $shifter, range( 0, $length - $span ) );
    ###var_dump($sp);
    $phrases["phrase$span"] = $sp;
}

print_r($phrases);
```